# Why do we assume that the population is normally distributed?

Tags: statistics

It was mentioned in an introductory statistics book I'm using that we should always assume that the parent population is normally distributed. Why is that?

Comment: nature loves a bell curve

Comment: It's a good, general assumption that holds reasonably well in many cases.  Of course, it doesn't always hold but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Is there a reason on why we do it?

Comment: There is something called the central limit theorem, which is used to approximate many distributions by a normal distribution when there is a large number of samples (or indeed a population)

Comment: If it really says just that, you need a better statistics textbook. But maybe there's some important context that you're leaving out.